# Azure APIM - Terraform errors out with ` A resource with the ID ... already exists` after creating API Operation

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

In my Azure APIM, I am trying to add API Operation to my API so I can add Policies to it via Terraform. All works fine except the `azurerm_api_management_api_operation` part. It basically errors out saying with the well known Terraform error `A resource with ID ... already exists..`.

A snippet of my Terraform is this:

```
    resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "business_api_v1" {
    name                = "business-api-v1"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.app_rg.name
    api_management_name = module.api.name
    revision            = "1"
    display_name        = "Business API v1"
    path                = "business-data/v1"
    protocols           = ["https"]
    version             = "v1"
    version_set_id      = azurerm_api_management_api_version_set.business-api-version-set.id

    import {
        content_format = "openapi+json"
        content_value  = <<JSON
            <...content of json open API spec...>
        JSON
    }
    }
    resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "search_businesses_v1" {
    operation_id        = "tf-search-businesses"
    api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.business_api_v1.name
    api_management_name = module.api.name
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.app_rg.name
    display_name        = "Search Businesses"
    method              = "GET"
    url_template        = "/businesses"
    description         = "Search Businesses by name"
    }
```

I am at loss as to why Terraform creates it and then gives the error:

```
A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/<sub_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group>/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/abcd/apis/business-api-v1/operations/tf-search-businesses" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" for more information.
```

I have deleted my API (& underlying resource in question) several times and ran the `plan` and `apply` stages. During `apply` stage it throws the error after creating the resource. 100% sure no one else created it I have tried renaming the `name` attribute several times as I attempted to troubleshoot this.

Anyone knows what might be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: So you did delete API operation resource?

Comment: @MarkoE yes manually via Portal before attempting to recreate it via Terraform.

Comment: Did you run ```terraform import```?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer - no I havent. Its little complicated in my org due to permission issues. 
But I am trying to work out why its asking to import when I created it via Terraform in first place. I have added prefix `tf-` so that there is no clash with existing resource. But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As terraform state file is created when the resource is deployed to
  azure and its state changes whenever resources are created .
- So as you said you have deleted the api operation via the UI i.e; the
  portal, the terraform state may have not matched with the real state.

As they are to be brought under terraform management control , do try to terraform import to match the existing changes as said by @markus by checking with the access from management.

```
terraform import <terraform_id> <azure_resource_id>
```

or

- Try deleting Terraform's local cache and all the resources and apply changes again .
- As terraform saved the state in local terraform.tfstate , try to
  manually change the backend.
- If you are tryting to change the name of a resource reference within
  your Terraform state file.

It can be done using `terraform state mv`

- If you wanted to remove resource created later but want to keep the
  actual one ,you can use

`terraform state rm {name of resource}`

Similar issues:

1. [terraform-provider-azurerm/issues.github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11076#issuecomment-963092635)
2. [terraform apply in Azure DevOps fails with "resource with the ID
   already exists" - DEV Community](https://dev.to/kopieczekdev/terraform-apply-in-azure-devops-fails-with-resource-with-the-id-already-exists-5694)